# Looking for smartphone style typing experience in native HTML

Tags: javascript, html, keyboard

I can't find anything like this looking online but I wanted to create a post to make sure that it's not just that google is not allowing me to find this.

I'm looking for a web implementation of a keyboard with word-level auto complete like smartphones and IDE's have. The keyboard would track what word the user is typing and make suggestions. It would automatically change which word is highlighted based on selection, handle insert of the auto complete item that was selected, etc.

Examples in the wild include VSCode and Google Translate (the website). In the latter case, you can type in the Japanese side and then fill in the Kanji from the typed in text.

Has anyone encountered something like this that is publically available?

Answer (score 0):

Hello probably you're searching for an API for grammar correction I searched for some of them like

- Spell Checker
- GrammarBot
- WebSpellChecker
- LanguageTool
- TextAnalysis
- Trinka.ai
- MODERATION API
- https://developer.grammarly.com/docs/autocomplete

The last one I think is the best one for what you're expecting.
If this don't satisfies you, sorry probably I misunderstood you. sorry for the english.

Comment: Actually I'm looking for an input component/library that will implement the complex interactions between typing, auto filling and maintaining the user's selection and the word they are actively typing in its state. Nothing to do with grammar. The end goal is to use this as a Japanese Keyboard without users having to use the fairly poor windows IME implementation and without asking them to have a google translate tab open for typing which would be ridiculous.

Comment: Obviously if I could get my hands on a literal web port of Swiftkey with language support (or a similar technology) that would be insane but I couldn't find anything like that.

Comment: Ok, sorry for it. I thought other things the last one I thought would satisfies you but I swear someone can help you